# How to cancel TextInput's onChange event when loading a file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to check if an image is smaller than 1mb, if it is larger, I have to cancel the event and not let react set the image in the input.
Even after verification and the condition is met, the image is being set to the input.

```
import { useField, useFormikContext } from 'formik';
import { Snack } from 'bnb-ui/dist'
import { useState } from 'react';

interface InputProps {
  name: string;
  disabled: boolean;
}

export function UploadField({ name, disabled }: InputProps) {
  const [field, mata] = useField(name);
  const { setFieldValue, values } = useFormikContext<any>();
  const [openSnack, setOpenSnack] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleChange = (evt: React.FormEvent) => {
    const { files, value } = evt.target as HTMLInputElement;

    if (files && files.length) {
      let file = files[0];
      if (file.size > 1024*1024) {
        setOpenSnack(true);
        return;
      } else {
        setFieldValue(name, value)
      };
    }
  }
}

return (
  <>
    <Snack open={openSnack} onClose={() => setOpenSnack(false)} message="O tamanho da imagem não pode ser superior a 1024Kb" variant="error" />
    <TextField
      disabled={disabled}
      placeholder="aaa"
      inputProps={{ accept: 'image/jpeg, image/png' }}
      type="file"
      variant="outlined"
      fullWidth
      onChange={handleChange}
      size="small"
      error={Boolean(mata && mata.touched && mata.error)}
      helperText={Boolean(mata && mata.touched && mata.error) && mata.error}
    />
  </>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.preventDefault() in a form event callback, which will prevent the default action from taking place upon the user's input, which in your case is the image file being set to the input. Something like this should work:

```js
if (file.size > 1024 * 1024) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  // You can do more things here too.
} else {
  // Do whatever u want with your file
}
```

Comment: That way it doesn't work. The path of the image being set in the input value